# goland/clion/idea quit unexpectdly in macos 13 ventura

Tags: intellij-idea, clion, goland

crash image

[image: 1]

I tried the following, but it still doesn't work
1.reboot mac
2.reinstall goland/clion/idea

Comment: I think there is a serious issue with all Jetbrains products after updating to Ventura. Webstorm crashes my system.  While Goland and pycharm strangle my mac where I cant work.

Answer (score 2):

open this file /Users/{USER_NAME}/Library/LaunchAgents/jetbrains.vmoptions.plist

and then remove all `launchctl setenv "*_OPTIONS"`.

save and close it.

reboot your mac.

now you can use jetbrain